# How to distribute ARKit applications?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight, arkit

How can I distribute iOS 11 ARKit app without using TestFlight?

Because uploading archive built with beta Xcode version to `Testflight` is not possible?

Comment: It is possible to use test flight (I've personally uploaded an archive for iOS11). You can't do it if you're on High Sierra, however.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys thanks, but i cannot upload to testflight, i get an error when sending the app. It archives well.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that your archive is failing. All I'm saying is that the problem is NOT because you're targeting iOS 11 with Xcode 9. [See my upload info page](http://imgur.com/a/JrYsU). If you give us more information, we might be able to figure out what is causing your error. What version of Xcode and macOS are you using. Is this app ALREADY in the App Store, and you're trying to add ARKit to it?

Comment: I had an issue with the xcode9 beta 1 and I had to update to the beta 2 to be able to upload ios11 apps to testflight. App will only be available to people who are running ios11 on their phones

Comment: It is xcode 9 beta 2 and MacOS Sierra.
No, app is not on the TestFlight, neither on AppStore, i just want to distribute my app so internal testers can test it...

Comment: and the error is:
Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

Comment: Try upgrading to Xcode 9 beta 3, it could be that Apple only allows from the latest Xcode beta. I think @Guig's experience might suggest this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but it can be tricky as the appropriate version of XCode changes often.

Right now, the current XCode beta is beta 6.

BUT, you can only upload to TestFlight using XCode beta 5. This limitation is only listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/).

It seems the TestFlight team lags behind the release schedule of the XCode beta versions.

You can download XCode beta 5 [here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_5/Xcode_9_beta_5.xip)